# Regex to extract only domain and subdomain for urls

Tags: regex, url, google-bigquery

I need to extract 2 domains from URl. For example, the web-site name is domain.domain2.com -> domain.domain2.com; but m.domain.domain2.com -> domain.domain2.com; also domain.domain2.com/london -> domain.domain2.com.

I have written an expression `^.+[\\./]([^\\.]+\\.[^\\.]+)$` but it always returns domain2.com.

What should I add to get the desired result?

Comment: To fix it, you must understand what the regex does. Do you? What kind of strings (*pattern*) do you want to match with it? Your examples are not quite helpful.

Comment: I want to extract string that contains '.com' thing and 2 (only!) next to '.com' domain names divided by dots.

Comment: Like `([^.]+)\.([^.]+2)\.com(?=\/|$)`? See https://regex101.com/r/t0EjI9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to extract string that contains '.com' thing and 2 (only!) next to '.com' domain names divided by dots

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'domain.domain2.com' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'm.domain.domain2.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'domain.domain2.com/london' 
)
SELECT *, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'([^.]+.[^.]+2.com)(?:/|$)') domain_and_subdomain
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row url                         domain_and_subdomain     
1   domain.domain2.com          domain.domain2.com   
2   m.domain.domain2.com        domain.domain2.com   
3   domain.domain2.com/london   domain.domain2.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [NET functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions#netreg_domain)

> select NET.HOST('http://m.domain.domain2.com/london')

returns:

m.domain.domain2.com

Comment: but I want m.domain.domain2.com -> domain.domain2.com

Comment: What's the logic to remove "m"?

Comment: To group m.domain.domain2.com and domain.domain2.com